# Automated export of CSV from mySQL using phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, csv, phpmyadmin, cron, cpanel

I am currently working on a project that requires an automated export of a CSV file from mySQL. I am using Cpanel with phpMyAdmin.

This is not an export of the entire database so I am unable to simply set a CRON task to do a mySQLDump. I have a procedure in place that links together the tables I need and a way to run that procedure as a scheduled task, but I now need a way to actually export the CSV with the data in that procedure creates and save the CSV file on the server.

Any ideas how to do this please?

Answer (score 2):

I think you will need to write a script to do the custom export.

If you are familiar with PHP, you can use the MySQLi library to connect to the database: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Once you have the rows to export, you can write them to a CSV file using: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Finally, setup a cron to run the script as frequently as needed.

For example:

`* * * * * /usr/bin/php my_export_script.php`

Comment: @WebblyBrown How about you post the code as a new answer? Then other people can benefit.